# How to use Wikidata to extract all cities of a country with some details via SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I'm interested in cities, towns, villages with their postal codes, states/provinces and official homepages.
The data exists mostly in Wikidata - I just seem to be unable to use SPARQL to extract it.

```
SELECT ?city ?cityLabel WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P17 wd:Q183;
    (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q515;
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?cityLabel
```

This basic approach returns plenty of records without a label. I assume, all cities, towns, villages have labels.
Additionally, it returns things like https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q436183 as well, which is not a city, town, village but rather a place of sorts.
Then I played around some more and came up with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cityLabel ?countyLabel ?officialHomepage
WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q515.
  ?city wdt:P17 wd:Q183.
  ?city wdt:P131 ?county.
  OPTIONAL { ?city wdt:P856 ?officialHomepage. }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de". }
}
```

There are only a few cities.
Does anybody have a good approach, on how to build the queries?
I understand the SQL somewhat, but putting wdt / wd etc. together is extremely hard for me.

Comment: regarding your first query: It's basically the correct query semantically. The issue is more that the data is not always perfect. Take for example the first result which is `wd:Q1011655` - it's obviously not a city but the type hierarchy goes from [hillfort](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q744099) -> [oppidum](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q192601) -> [Roman city](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2202509) -> and at this point you can imagine it geos up to "city" type

Comment: Also, indeed not every entity has a label in Wikidata - at least not in every language. In your query you are asking for English labels only, but if you again go to the first result of your query `wd:Q1011655` and given that you aks for German cities there is only a German label here with "Burg Esesfeld". I mean, of course it's not a city anyways, but it can happen that for some entities you won't find an English label

Comment: Your second query is way more restrictive. It has be a direct type of "city" (there are plenty of "good" subtypes which you will miss then) and you are also requiring facts about geospatial containment which might also be missing for some cities

Comment: All you could to to refine the first query is to add a bunch of excluding filters I'd say - and this might indeed be not perfect unless you spotted all data errors in Wikidata. `FILTER NOT EXIST{ ... }` would be the pattern to go, e.g. omit ancient cities and the like then